# Font size across mobile devices and desktops

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to have a web-page show a reasonable font size across desktop and mobile devices.

I'm testing on my Pixel 3 which has as many pixels as my desktop.

I've set:

```
font-size: 16px;
```

When I load the page on my cell the font is tiny. My

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
```

Doesn't react. I presume that's because the Pixel 3 display is large.

I've tried to set:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

And to then use font-size: 1vh. That didn't seem to work either. Sorry for the noob question. The other articles generally suggested @media but as far as I can tell newer cells have so large screens that @media doesn't work well with pixel math.

Bottom line: What does a simple reasonable HTML5/CSS3 page look like to have a readable font size across desktops and mobiles?

Comment: If you don't set any font-size yourself you automatically have reasonable size set for all devices. Only works as long as the size is not too big/small ;)

Comment: Amazing! What a difference :))) I just killed the one single place I had been misled to insert a font-size and viola now it's fantastic. 16px on a high res mobile screen is nearly unreadable :-D. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it as a solution.

Comment: Also be aware that there are two "sizes" a mobile device can have. They might have a high, real resolution (like HD or even up to 4k, whatever). They still "define" themselves as only 700px or something wide when it comes to mediaqueries. This has historical reasons and it works till now, so you might look up what's the media-query size for a phone.

Comment: The result was unexpected. When I removed the don't size the media query suddenly detected it as a smaller device and removed my flex colums. Which was a nice unexpected benefit :-) so what you're describing kind of happened

Answer (score 1):

@media should work if you are doing it correctly. However, what you can do is this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Change the values of "initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0," according to your need. I hope this helps.

Or something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
your style
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 981px) {
your style
}
```

Comment: Why does media work when Pixel3 has 1080x2160 pixels? Unless @media does something else than apparent, media can't tell the difference between my desktop and mobile. Both have > 800px. I've tried initial-scale. That didn't work. I'll try max and see

Comment: To differentiate between mobile and desktop, you need to use at media with "max-width" and another at media with "min-width" in your CSS. I edited my answer above with an example, check it out.

Comment: @John no to differentiate you don't need to use `min-` and `max-width` together. You can  use one of these (see mobile- or desktop-first development) and just overwrite the styles you need. You **can** use both but you don't need to.